# ESC/POS Print Driver for PHP trouble shooting

Tags: php, printing, escpos

I am using ESC/POS Print Driver for PHP (https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/) for thermal printing ,

I have successfully took my first print with following code :

```
require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\NetworkPrintConnector;

$connector = new NetworkPrintConnector("192.xxx.x.xxx");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
    $printer -> text("this is my first print");
    $printer -> feed();
    $printer -> feed();
    $printer -> cut();
    $printer -> close();
```

Now, I want that if **printer is not working then an error should display to user**
  (basic troubleshoot like Plug is off, power disconnected, out of paper.)

Please suggest me an option to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `try{ } catch { }` to find issues with the initialization of `NetworkPrintConnector`. This will catch some show-stopper issues, such as a printer that is powered off or inaccessible over the network.

For a printer error like "cover open" or "out of paper", the exact way to find the status varies between printer manufacturers. [No method is availble](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/43) in escpos-php at the time of writing for getting the printer status.

If you are have a networked Epson printer, then you can use the Auto-Status-Back (ASB) feature on the embedded print server, which involves sending a UDP datagram and parsing the response: [example](https://gist.github.com/defacto133/5a22db20185cd1cdc9f6).